# Uso de if __name__=='__main__'. Por quê a classe não é instanciada?

Tags: python

Tem pouco tempo que estou usando o Python e existe algumas coisas que ainda fico confuso, a minha dúvida é neste código:

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class PythonOrgSearch(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def test_search_in_python_org(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("http://www.python.org")
        self.assertIn("Python", driver.title)
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        elem.send_keys("pycon")
        elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Por quê no "`if __name__ == "__main__":`" ele não instanciou a classe `PythonOrgSearch` e por quê ao colocar o comando "`unittest.main()`" ele executou as ações da classe PythonOrgSearch? Desta forma não fica mais confuso? Alguém pode explicar por quê ele fez desta forma?

Comment: O "if __name__ == "__main__":" não esta na classe "PythonOrgSearch"

Comment: Isso tem mais a ver com o como o framework `unittest` é usado do que com código `Python` puro

Comment: Concordo com o @JeffersonQuesado, tenta mudar os argumentos da classe para object

Comment: Entendi que é por causa do framework, mas ainda estou com o mesmo problema, se eu encontrar um código desta forma eu não vou saber que unittest.main() executara a classe PythonOrgSearch, como posso identificar isso, sem precisar executar o código.

Comment: Conhecendo o código é a única forma. A biblioteca `unittest` faz coisas que parecem mágicas mesmo, não seguindo muito a filosofia do "explícito é melhor que o implícito".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por partes:
Seu bloco `class` com a declaração da classe cria a classe sim - não cria uma instância da classe. Em Python isso seria feito usando o nome da classe como se fosse uma chamada a função: `PythonOrgSearch()`. (Sem precisar da palavra chave `new` como em Java e JavaScript).

O que acontece que a classe `unittest.TestCase` é especial no sentido de que o programador não precisa instanciar as subclasses: ao se chamar a função `unittest.main()`, o código lá se encarrega de usar introspecção para achar as subclasses de `TestCase` e executar os testes contidos nelas.  Na prática, elas mal são usadas como "classes", exceto pelo fato de que você pode criar atributos no método de `setup` que vão estar disponíveis para os métodos de "teste".

Ou seja: esse arquivo de código declara a classe e só isso. O que faz os testes serem executados quando se chama `unittest.main` é o próprio código que está lá (em Python mesmo, é só abrir o arquivo e ver - apesar de ter muitas camadas de extras para tratar exceções, etc...). e isso é feito por que foi uma forma interessante que pensaram na época para disparar a execução de um grupo de testes - não tem nada de especial na linguagem em relação a isso. Sem esse código dentro do `unittest.main()` esse arquivo simplesmente não faria nada.

Já a linha que parece especial `if __name__ == "__main__":` é um pattern muito usado em Python baseado na variável especial `__name__`: a própria linguagem seta essa variável para ser igual o nome do arquivo `.py` em execução, **exceto** quando esse arquivo é o programa principal em execução. (Isso é: você chamou `python arquivo.py`. ) Nesse caso, o valor dessa variável é "`__main__`" (e não "arquivo"). Então, o que esse  `if` faz é definir um bloco de código que só será executado se o arquivo atual for chamado como programa principal do Python, mas *não quando ele for importado em outro arquivo*, com o comando `import`.

O jeito padrão de escrever testes coloca nesse bloco a chamada do `unittet.main`, que faz o que eu descrevi acima. Fora algumas coisas especiais no logging, e tratamento de exceções, fazer o que esse `unittest.main`  faz não é nada de outro mundo - e, uma forma simplificada pode ser feita em pouquissimas linhas. Um módulo `unittest` mínimo poderia ser:

```
class TestCase(object):
    def setUp(self):
        pass
    def tearDown(self):
        pass


def main():
   errors = []
   passed = 0
   failed = 0
   for cls in TestCase.__subclasses__():
       # acima teria que ser um pouco mais
       # sofisticado: o metodo __sublasses__
       # só  devolve as subclasses imediatas (mas não as  'netas')
       for attribute in cls.__dict__:
           if not attribute.startswith("test_"):
               continue
           if not callable cls.__dict__[attribute]:
               continue
           # A linha abaixo cria a instancia da classe em si.
           # Uma instância para cada método de teste:
           instance = cls()
           instance.setUp()
           try:
               # Execut o método de teste
               getattr(instance, attribute)()
           except Exception as err:
               message = "F"
               failed += 1
               erros.append(str(err))
           else:
               message = "."
               passed += 1
           finally:
               instance.tearDown() 
           print(message, end=" ", flush=True)

     print(f"\n\nFinished. Total tests: {failed + passed}, passed: {passed}, failed: {failed}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Vejo que ja tem uma resposta com uma boa explanação teórica, então vou responder sem me preocupar com o funcionamento do TesteCase, baseado nos comentáriios, vou tentar induzir o autor da pergunta a entender o significado do `if __name__ == __main__`

Vamos criar um script chamado foo.py

```
import bar
print ('Nome do modulo no arquivo foo.py:',__name__)
```

E outro chamado bar.py

```
print ('Nome do modulo no arquivo bar.py:',__name__)
```

Executamos foo.py vejamoos o resultado:

```
$ python foo.py
Nome do módulo, no arquivo bar.py:  bar
Nome do modulo no arquivo foo.py: __main__
```

> Veja que na chamada a foo o `__name__` do modulo no scritp que foi chamado é `__main__`, como bar foi chamado de forma 'indireta', o nome dele é o nome do proprio script, mas se vc chama-lo individualmente, veja o resultado:

```
$ python bar.py 
Nome do módulo, no arquivo bar.py:  __main__
```

Agora vamos alterar os arquivos para que `bar` chame `foo`, assim:

foo.py

```
print ('Nome do modulo no arquivo foo.py:',__name__)
```

bar.py

```
import foo
print ('Nome do módulo, no arquivo bar.py ', __name__)
```

Veja agora o resultado quando executamos foo:

```
$ python foo.py 
Nome do modulo no arquivo foo.py: __main__
```

> O nome de `foo` aqui é `__main__`, porque esta sendo chamado como modulo principal, agora veja quando chamamos bar.

```
$ python bar.py 
Nome do modulo no arquivo foo.py: foo
Nome do módulo, no arquivo bar.py  __main__
```

> Quando chamamos bar, ele é, agora, `__main__` e como ele chama `foo`, esse passa a ser, digamos secundário e perde o nome `__main__`

Comment: Quando se usa o `from bar import baz`, também imprimiria o `Nome do módulo, no arquivo bar.py  bar`?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, se entendi seu questionamento, a resposta é Sim. Veja q no primeiro exemplo, só de ter importado `bar`, a saida foi o `print` do `bar` primeiro (resultante do `import`) e o `print` do `foo`. A saida de `bar` não seria apresentada se o comando tivesse dentro do `if __name__=='__main__:`, mas eu não quis fazer isso exatamente para forçar o raciocínio.