# Processos em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, processo

Estou estudando o módulo `multiprocessing` e em todos os exemplos na *[documentação do Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)* existe sempre uma `if` verificação nos exemplos, eu sei que isso verifica se o arquivo está sendo executado diretamente ou sendo importado mas tem alguma relação com a inicialização de um `processo`?

> The multiprocessing module also introduces APIs which do not have
>   analogs in the threading module. A prime example of this is the Pool
>   object which offers a convenient means of parallelizing the execution
>   of a function across multiple input values, distributing the input
>   data across processes (data parallelism). The following example
>   demonstrates the common practice of defining such functions in a
>   module so that child processes can successfully import that module.
>   This basic example of data parallelism using Pool,

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: "*se o módulo foi importado ou não*", onde isso?

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata: [Uso de if \_\_name\_\_=='\_\_main\_\_'. Por quê a classe não é instanciada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236656/5878)

Comment: As edições ajudaram muito a entender sua pergunta. Eu crio que o uso do 'if __name__ == '__main__' ' Seja apenas para deixar mais didático o exemplo dado na documentação. Posso estar errado. Vou acompanhar o post

Comment: "se o módulo foi importado ou não", - sim, é exatamente isso. - a condição  ` `  `  __name__== '__main__' `   é verdadeira quando o módulo é o arquivo principal em execução no runtime do Python - aí a varíavel `__name__` assume  o valor `__main__` - se o módulo atual for importado a partir de outro módulo Python essa variável terá o nome do módulo.

Answer (score 1):

Esta condição faz com que o `Pool` seja iniciado apenas se o programa for chamado diretamente, como o módulo `multiprocessing` também chamará este programa para rodar a função `f()` para cada instância do *pool* isto evita que o trecho de inicialização seja executado uma segunda vez e produzindo um *loop* infinito.

Comment: Na verdade, o multiprocessing usa `fork` (em sistemas operacionais, no DOS não sei dizer) - então o mecanismo é diferente - pode até ser que se você testar a variável `__name__` dentro de um worker do multiprocessing ela seja `__main__` também. De qualquer forma, esse bloco é executado apenas no processo principal. 

Mas nada impede que se use esse bloco apenas pra chamar uma função "principal" que tenha toda a lógica - não precisa haver mais código que isso dentro dele.